# MongoDB Connection created for every AWS serverless function call

Tags: express, mongoose, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have set up Express js with Serverless and connecting to  mongoDb atlas.
The Code works fine, but It creates a connection for each call. I tried the Caching method also, but no luck with it. 
Here is my code below

```
// server.js
const sls = require('serverless-http')
const connectToDatabase = require('./lib/db');

const app = require('./lib/app')
connectToDatabase();
module.exports.run = sls(app)



//db.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Promise = require("bluebird");
// console.log("Connecting to " + process.env.DB);
const connection = {}
mongoose.Promise= Promise;

module.exports = async () => {
  if (connection.isConnected) {
    console.log('=> using existing database connection')
    return
  }

  console.log('=> using new database connection')
  const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB,{useNewUrlParser:true})
  connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check:

- How long does your Lambda function take to execute? Your function will only handle one request at a time. If you make a second request before your first request completes a new instance of your function will spin up.
- Ensure that mongoose isn't closing the connection after your function completes.

Comment: It takes like 1500 milli to execute a function. Iv searched everywhere, couldn't find a way to cache the mongoose. but theres a workaround for Mongodb native nodejs driver.